# Multiplicar 2 columnas MySQL con decimales

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una columna llamada `PRECIO` y otra `CANTIDAD`, la columna `PRECIO` esta en formato text y el separador de decimales tiene una coma, (esto es el resultado de una exportación de excel a mysql).

Logre multiplicar `PRECIO` x `CANTIDAD`con esta función:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set totales = cantidad * precio");
```

Ahora necesito que el resultado introducido en `totales` contenga 2 decimales.

¿Que falta por hacer, para obtener el resultado con 2 decimales considerando que el valor a multiplicar que contiene el decimal esta con coma y en formato text?

<sub>NOTA: No puedo pasar el formato text a decimal por que cuando importa el campo omite los decimales.</sub>

while:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; $handle = fopen($file, "r"); $id = 0; while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) { $cantidad = $filesop[10]; $precio = $filesop[11]; $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLAX (id, cantidad, precio) VALUES ('$id++','$cantidad','$precio') }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64185/discussion-on-question-by-ivan-diaz-perez-multiplicar-2-columnas-mysql-con-decim).

Comment: No entiendo la nota final que pones. Si no puedes absolutamente cambiar el diseño de la tabla, haciendo que almacene los campos en sus tipos de datos más recomendados, ok, busca soluciones _forzadas_ las cuales casi siempre dan problemas, por errores en los datos o por lo que sea. Ahora bien, si puedes modificar la tabla almacena los campos decimales en columnas específicas para ese tipo de dato. Si haces una importación desde otro sitio puedes crear un script que haga la importación, convirtiendo los datos a decimal.

Comment: ok originalmente tengo 2 columnas en formato text una precio otra cantidad, ambas son producto de una importacion desde un csv a mysql, no se como convertir el campo precio extraido del csv antes de insertarlo en la importacion. $precio = $filesop[2];

Comment: Si tienes la posibilidad de modificar la tabla, es lo más recomendable. La columna precio debería ser del tipo `decimal`, tendrás menos riesgo de error y más facilidad y precisión para hacer cálculos. Si almacenas un campo numérico o decimal como `text` tendrás problemas tarde o temprano, a parte de tener una tabla poco optimizada. Para una posible respuesta es bueno que indiques cuál es el separador de columnas del csv y de los valores decimales. [Aquí tienes una posibilidad de hacerlo directamente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697449/5587982) previa modificación de la columna `precio`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) en el `UPDATE` de la siguiente manera para guardar los datos calculados en un campo de tipo `TEXT`, `CHAR`, etc:

```
UPDATE
  pruebas
SET
  totales = REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(cantidad * precio, 2), ',', ''), '.', ',');
```

Aquí puedes ver un [ejemplo en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tw4afyjeTmDhDFnmsLdZPV/1).

El formato de número en MySQL es, por defecto, `#,###.##`, de modo que primero elimino las comas de los miles reemplándolas por una cadena vacía y luego los puntos decimales por una coma, de manera similar que hice en PHP con `str_replace`.

Lo ideal es que usaras datos nativos de MySQL y que al leer el archivo de excel (que parece que es un CSV) hagas la conversión antes de guardar los datos:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$id = 0;
for ($id = 0; ($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false; $id++) {
  $cantidad = mysql_real_escape_string(
    str_replace(',', '.', $filesop[10])
  );
  $precio = mysql_real_escape_string(
    str_replace(',', '.',$filesop[11])
  );
  $sql = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO TABLAX (
      id,
      cantidad,
      precio
    ) VALUES (
      '$id',
      '$cantidad',
      '$precio'
    )
  ");
}
```

Te aconsejo encarecidamente que dejes de usar las funciones `mysql_*` porque fueron marcadas como obsoletas en PHP 5.5 y eliminadas completamente a partir de PHP 7.0, y migrar tu código a [`PDO-mysql`](http://php.net/pdo-mysql) o [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli).

[Respuesta anterior con ejemplos de formato en PHP y MySQL.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/96323/1)

Comment: Vale he probado y el resultado de totales debe ser decimal con coma.

lo que hace ahora es: 10 * 1,3 = 10,00 cuando deberia de ser 13,00

Comment: Estás cometiendo un error en algún punto del proceso. No se puede multiplicar `10 * 1,3`. Debe multiplicarse `10 * 1.3`. Si quieres hacer la conversión inversa entonces debes realizar las sustituciones inversas (`REPLACE('1,3', ',', '.')`). Si puedes ponerme un ejemplo del origen de datos, cómo los lees, cómo los grabas y te diré cómo solucionar el proceso completo.

Comment: ok originalmente entra este dato en la tabla de esta forma: cantidad = 10 precio = 1,3 el resultado de multiplicar cantidad * precio debe ser 13,00 debo entonces realizar dos conversiones? una que me reemplace la coma por punto, hacer la multiplicación y volver a convertir el punto en coma.?? ni idea

Comment: Realmente lo estás planteando mal desde el origen. A la base de datos deben llegar datos correctos, de modo que debes convertir lo que lees del excel a valores nativos de MySQL y no en cadenas de caracteres para mantener el formato localizado. Al mostrarlo en una web o volver a crear un Excel de salida deberás volver a convertir el formato nativo en localizado.

Comment: Vale estoy claro que de origen viene mal, si pudiera cambiar el origen seria un exito pero no tengo acceso a cambiarlo de origen, llega asi entonces me toca, cambiar a punto, multiplicar y cambiar a coma es la unica forma que veo de hacer esto, a menos que del csv pueda antes de insertar cambiar la coma por el punto.?

Comment: Por supuesto que puedes (y debes) hacerlo en ese momento. Si compartes el bucle que hace uso de `fgetcsv` puedo ayudarte a adaptarlo.

Comment: $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $handle = fopen($file, "r");
  $id = 0;
  while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false)
  {

   $cantidad = $filesop[10];
   $precio = $filesop[11];
   
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLAX (id, cantidad, precio) VALUES ('$id++','$cantidad','$precio')
   }

Comment: donde precio viene con coma en el csv entonces antes de insertarlo en mysql deberia de cambiarlo a punto y despues insertar

Comment: ¿Podrías agregarlo como edición de tu pregunta? Como comentario se corta y no mantiene formato.

Comment: Ya he hecho una edición para mostrarte un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Comment: muchas gracias si logre el resultado, el error era de origen del csv esta correcto muchas gracias

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! Me alegra saber que dimos con la solución al problema.

Comment: ok ya logre insertar la multiplicacion perfectamente ahora el resultado de la multiplicacion debe mostrarse con coma no con punto, no se si despues del update puedo insertar el cambio y como sera el codigo? o si visualmente puedo hacer un echo o print que me reemplace el punto por la coma?? Muchas Gracias

Comment: Cuando quieras mostrar un resultado con el formato deseado puedes hacerlo con `FORMAT` o con funciones de PHP como te mostré en la edición original. Estoy fuera de casa, cuando vuelva haré un resumen del proceso en la respuesta. Si te fue de ayuda o resolvió el problema agradecería que la marcaras como correcta, gracias.